# AWS: Getting the list of TargetGroups that contains a certain string and use the result json in the next CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

In my use-case, I have the epoch time appended to the target group names, for example: `TG-1568112242342 and TG-1568112427511`. Now I am supposed to get the latest two target groups based on the epoch attached to the name, i.e. 1568112427511 and 1568112242342. and then use the TargetGroupArn of the latest two target groups to change the listener rules in one of the ALBs.

In order to get the latest two Target groups I am trying to run this but getting empty json:
`aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query "[? TargetGroups[? starts_with(TargetGroupName, 'TG')]][].TargetGroupName"`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Update: I tried this also as recommended [here](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/) but still returns empty json:

`aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query "TargetGroups[?starts_with(TargetGroupName, 'TG') == 'true']|[0:5].[TargetGroupName]"`

Comment: The problem is that you need to use ` instead of ' inside your query between true and Target Group name. Here's the command you need to use: `aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query 'TargetGroups[?starts_with(TargetGroupName, \`TG\`) == \`true\`].[TargetGroupName]'`

Comment: Ahh, that was silly of me. thanks @krishna_mee2004